# No reaction when "..." clicked on a TCollectionItem property that represents another TCollection

Tags: delphi, tcollection, tcollectionitem

I've never been in a situation that needed it, and this is the first time I try to have a `TCollection` as `TCollectionItem` of another `TCollection`.
It all compiles fine, but there is no reaction when the three dots behind the `TCollectionItem`'s `TCollection` property are clicked, ie. the dialog with the list of that sub-`TCollection` does not appear.

I was under the impression that, since no fancy property editors should be necessary (the sub-`TCollection` only carries items that have a `string` and a `single` property), the IDE would pretty much handle it automatically.

Apparently that's not the case, or I'm overseeing the obvious, which is a chronic affliction.

The implementation (run-time) unit has this:

```
type

  TBitmapItemTag = class(TCollectionItem)
  private
    FTagName: string;
    FTagFloat: Single;
  published
    property TagName: string read FTagName write FTagName;
    property TagFloat: Single read FTagFloat write FTagFloat;
  end;

  TBitmapItemTags = class(TOwnedCollection)

  end;

  TBitmapItem = class(TCollectionItem)
  private
    FBitmap: TBitmap;
    FBitmapItemTags: TBitmapItemTags;
  public
    constructor Create(Collection: TCollection); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    property Bitmap: TBitmap read FBitmap write FBitmap;
    property Tags: TBitmapItemTags read FBitmapItemTags write FBitmapItemTags;
  end;

  TBitmaps = class(TCollection)

  end;

  TBitmapCollection = class(TComponent)
  private
    FBitmaps: TBitmaps;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    property Bitmaps: TBitmaps read FBitmaps write FBitmaps;
  end;

implementation

{ TBitmapItem }

constructor TBitmapItem.Create(Collection: TCollection);
begin
  inherited Create(Collection);
  FBitmap := TBitmap.Create(0, 0);
  FBitmapItemTags := TBitmapItemTags.Create(Self,TBitmapItemTag);
end;

destructor TBitmapItem.Destroy;
begin
  FBitmap.Free;
  FBitmapItemTags.Free;
  inherited;
end;

{ TBitmapCollection }

constructor TBitmapCollection.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  FBitmaps := TBitmaps.Create(TBitmapItem);
end;

destructor TBitmapCollection.Destroy;
begin
  FBitmaps.Free;
  inherited;
end;
```

The `Register` procedure is implemented in the design-time unit and just calls the `RegisterComponents` procedure. And holds some lazy `RegisterPropertyEditor` tries that were to no avail.

If anyone can point me to the shortest path in order for the IDE to recognize the `TBitmapItemTag TCollectionItem`, I'd be grateful.

Comment: Use `TOwnedCollection` instead of `TCollection`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change `TBitmaps` to derive from `TOwnedCollection` instead of `TCollection`.

I also suggest defining explicit constructors for `TBitmapItemTags` and `TBitmaps`.

You also need to add some setter methods to your object-based properties, otherwise you risk memory leaks at runtime.  Your setters should be calling `Assign()` on your objects to copy property values from one object to another.  `TCollection` already implements `Assign()` for you, but you will have to implement `Assign()` in your collection items.

Try this:

```
type
  TBitmapItemTag = class(TCollectionItem)
  private
    FTagName: string;
    FTagFloat: Single;
  public
    procedure Assign(ASource: TPersistent); override;
  published
    property TagName: string read FTagName write FTagName;
    property TagFloat: Single read FTagFloat write FTagFloat;
  end;

  TBitmapItem = class;

  TBitmapItemTags = class(TOwnedCollection)
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TBitmapItem); reintroduce;
  end;

  TBitmapItem = class(TCollectionItem)
  private
    FBitmap: TBitmap;
    FTags: TBitmapItemTags;
    procedure SetBitmap(AValue: TBitmap);
    procedure SetTags(AValue: TBitmapItemTags);
  public
    constructor Create(Collection: TCollection); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure Assign(ASource: TPersistent); override;
  published
    property Bitmap: TBitmap read FBitmap write SetBitmap;
    property Tags: TBitmapItemTags read FTags write SetTags;
  end;

  TBitmapCollection = class;

  TBitmaps = class(TOwnedCollection)
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TBitmapCollection); reintroduce;
  end;

  TBitmapCollection = class(TComponent)
  private
    FBitmaps: TBitmaps;
    procedure SetBitmaps(AValue: TBitmaps);
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    property Bitmaps: TBitmaps read FBitmaps write SetBitmaps;
  end;
```

```
{ TBitmapTagItem }

procedure TBitmapItemTag.Assign(ASource: TPersistent);
begin
  if ASource is TBitmapItemTag then
  begin
    FTagName := TBitmapItemTag(ASource).TagName;
    FTagFloat := TBitmapItemTag(ASource).TagFloat;
  end
  else
    inherited;
end;

{ TBitmapItemTags }

constructor TBitmapItemTags.Create(AOwner: TBitmapItem);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner, TBitmapItemTag);
end;

{ TBitmapItem }

constructor TBitmapItem.Create(Collection: TCollection);
begin
  inherited Create(Collection);
  FBitmap := TBitmap.Create(0, 0);
  FTags := TBitmapItemTags.Create(Self);
end;

destructor TBitmapItem.Destroy;
begin
  FBitmap.Free;
  FTags.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TBitmapItem.Assign(ASource: TPersistent);
begin
  if ASource is TBitmapItem then
  begin
    FBitmap.Assign(TBitmapItem(ASource).Bitmap);
    FTags.Assign(TBitmapItem(ASource).Tags);
  end
  else
    inherited;
end;

procedure TBitmapItem.SetBitmap(AValue: TBitmap);
begin
  FBitmap.Assign(AValue);
end;

procedure TBitmapItem.SetTags(AValue: TBitmapItemTags);
begin
  FTags.Assign(AValue);
end;

{ TBitmaps }

constructor TBitmaps.Create(AOwner: TBitmapCollection);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner, TBitmapItem);
end;

{ TBitmapCollection }

constructor TBitmapCollection.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  FBitmaps := TBitmaps.Create(Self);
end;

destructor TBitmapCollection.Destroy;
begin
  FBitmaps.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TBitmapCollection.SetBitmaps(AValue: TBitmaps);
begin
  FBitmaps.Assign(AValue);
end;
```

Comment: This is so much more than "pointing me in the right direction"! Immensely grateful, Remy, for the six hundredth time.

Comment: @Domus How can you thank him 600 times when you've only asked 25 questions? =P

Comment: @JerryDodge I've been bugging Remy with questions since 1995, I think; long before the idea of anything resembling Stack Overflow started germinating in Jeff or Joel's brain. ;)

Comment: @RemyLebeau Would there be any problem if I changed the constructor of TBitmaps to "constructor Create(AOwner: TPersistent); reintroduce?" I need to do that to avoid incompatibilities with the rest of the application, where I need TBitmaps without it being owned by the TBitmapCollection component.

Comment: @Domus: that will work fine. The important thing is that the `ItemClass` parameter should not be exposed, as that allows the user of the collection to potentially set a class type that is not compatible with the rest of the collection's code. The collection's constructor should assign the appropriate class type internally. That is why I like to `reintroduce` a new constructor to hide the `ItemClass` parameter